# port forward ppp0 to eth0 in ubuntu server

Tags: vpn, port-forwarding, ubuntu-server

After I establish vpn connection to ubuntu server I see `ppp0` have created. So I have to port forward `ppp0` to `eth0`, not all port but at least 22, 80 & 443. how do I do it?

Comment: I'm fairly certain you want to route those requests (or perform reverse proxy-ing); port forwarding would just route them to another tcp socket listener.

Comment: Ideally I can't ssh to ubuntu server over VPN that's where I end up with port forwarding. Tried these rules but it's not working `sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE;
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o ppp0 -j ACCEPT;
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i ppp0 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT;`